Nginx close transport between upstream after upstream sending too many messages
I have an gRPC upstream server behind my Nginx reverse proxy server.
And client sends a single-direction stream request to Nginx to ask for informations from the server.
For some reason, client does not read for longer than one minute. After that, Nginx close the transport connection between upstream and Nginx. When my client reads from the stream, I get unexpected EOF error.
Some situation I have found

If the total size of messages sent by upstream does not reach about 130 KB, Nginx will not close the transport connection.
The transport connection will only end one minute after the 130 KB limitation is reached.

Here is my Nginx config:
server {
//...
  client_header_timeout 6h;
  location /example.Greeter {
      grpc_read_timeout 6h;
      grpc_send_timeout 6h;
      client_body_timeout 6h;

      grpc_pass grpcs://greeting_server;
  }
//...
}

upstream greeting_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:50051;
}


I wonder which directive should I set to prevent the connection from closing.
